# continue process after responding to Ajax request jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

```
var getPageInhalt : function (id){
    var restmethod = "http://localhost:1212/getPageById/"+id+"/jsonp.aspx?callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        url: restmethod,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,                        
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        error: function(){
            return false;
        },
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data); --> balblal
            return data;
        }
    });
}

console.log(getPageInhalt(2));-->undefined ?????
```

Comment: If I had £1 for every question about returning values from async functions...

Comment: There is no return statement in the `getPageInhalt` function. That said, please don't make synchronous Ajax requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although i disagree with synchronous AJAX (*technically it is an oxymoron ..*) you will have to return the value from the `getPageInhalt` function and not from the ajax callbacks..

```
var getPageInhalt = function (id){
    var restmethod = "http://localhost:1212/getPageById/"+id+"/jsonp.aspx?callback=?",
        resultValue;

    $.ajax({
        url: restmethod,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,                        
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        error: function(){
            resultValue = false;
        },
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data); //--> balblal
            resultValue = data;
        }
    });

    return resultValue;
}
```

**Here is a demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qHY7g/

Comment: change `var getPageInhalt : ` to `var getPageInhalt = ` since that was a syntax error.. (*use `=` instead of `:`*)

Comment: var page ={
   getPageInhalt : function (id){ --my function---}}

Comment: @samibel, ok... here is the updated demo (*that works*) with this syntax.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qHY7g/

Comment: this is my console answer :log result: undefined
success: blaball

Comment: that is the result you get of the jsfiddle example ? (*it cant really be, cause i get the right result on IE, Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera*) (*what browser you use?*).. Or is it what you get when you put it in your own code/app ?

Comment: @samibel, you might not be able to do this, because the `JSONP` request is not using the classic ajax interface.. it uses a script tag innjected in the code.. the result is that the callbacks are being simulated with timeouts and this makes them not run in-time for your functions return.. best think i can suggest is to re-work your structure and pass the code you want executed to the `success` callback and the relevant code to the `error` callback..